# Javascript Dynamically Add Option Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a select tagged element but I want to fill this with my model's data, but I can't do it.

This is my code:

```
<select id=senderAdress" + element + " class=senderAdressText2> </select>

var element = 0;
while(element!==3){
  var obj = document.getElementById("senderAdress"+element);
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.value=element+1;
  opt.text = "@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Address[element].AddressName)";
  element++;
}
```

This is not working because in the opt.text part as you can see I want to reach my model's addressName where my Address[element]. At the top of my while I created a variable "element" and I assigned it as 0.

The problem is when I wrote Address[element] I got an error which tells me

> The name element does not exist in current context,

but as you can see I assigned it at top and if it is not reachable why my while loop shows me an error.

Comment: What is `type=text` on a select?

Comment: At first it was an input, then I changed to select. It was from input, I forgot to change it. Thanks.

Comment: Show all relevant code ...in html alone `id=senderAdress" + element + "` is invalid. Html isn't a programming language that can compile that

Comment: I am doing these things using javascript, under script tag.

Comment: Show the actual code then please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to mix some server side logic with client side javascript. The `element` variable is a javascript variable. This means that it exists only on the client. On the other hand the model is a server side concept which doesn't have access to client side variables. So you may consider storing those server side values in a javascript variable if you want to be able to access them:

```
var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(item => Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address(item).AddressName).ToString())));
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('senderAdress' + i);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i + 1;
    opt.text = values[i];
}
```

Of course a much better solution would be to use the strongly typed `Html.DropDownListFor` server side helper to generate your drop down lists on the server directly.

Comment: Hey Darin, I made some changes at your code and it is really work fine but I want to ask you a question. At Enumerable.Range(0,3) I don't want to set range as 3 I want to set the count of the my list. How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the range as 3 then simply use the `Count` of your model: `Enumerable.Range(0, model.Address.Count())`.

Comment: Hey, when I did like you write it sends me error like model is nox exist in current context. It must be int value at range. How can I change this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing Javascript and C# in your Razor template. The C# part can't access the varable defined in the Javascript part. Why don't you do everything in C#?

If you want to do that in JS, and if you know all items beforehand, you would need to store all values from your model into a JS array for instance. In that case, the element index would correspond to a local JS variable.

Comment: I don't know how can I do in server side.

Comment: How can I reach my select Id in server side, because I  think I can't use document.getElementById() in serverside.

Comment: Have a look at: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx